# Cannot login to Joomla back or front end nor view getting started article after fresh install

Tags: authentication, joomla, serializable

I've installed Joomla 3.4.4 (twice) with exactly the same outcome.

Problems:
- when entering ANY information into the username and password field on the back end login page, the page refreshed back to the login page without any errors or warnings on the page or in the server logs.
- the same for trying to login on the front end.
- When visiting the site, below the site title and header image a message is displayed "Error: You are not authorised to view this resource."

Both after and before installing joomla I uploaded a .user.ini to turn off magic quotes.
The configuration.php has correct settings for life site, session time out and a correct location for logs and temp files.
I've verified that the logs and tmp directory are writeable from Joomla (added code to create and write to a file in both directories).
I've checked all the modules and plugins in the database.
I've set session_save_path to a location that is writeable.
I've ruled out redirections from .htaccess.
I've enabled all messages to be displayed.
A valid cookie is sent to the browser and back to the site.
The jos1 database contains the cookies sent to the browser
The jos1 database has correct settings for both user and group

There was an warning about an unserializable object I've checked out. It's in Registry.php line 100:

```
public function __clone()
{
    $this->data = unserialize(serialize($this->data));      
}
```

When `print_r`ing $this->data the following is shown:

```
��j Object
(
    [article_layout] => _:default
    [show_title] => 1
    [link_titles] => 1
    [show_intro] => 1
    [show_category] => 1
    [link_category] => 1
    [show_parent_category] => 0
    [link_parent_category] => 0
    [show_author] => 1
    [link_author] => 0
    [show_create_date] => 0
    [show_modify_date] => 0
    [show_publish_date] => 1
    [show_item_navigation] => 1
    [show_vote] => 0
    [show_readmore] => 1
    [show_readmore_title] => 1
    [readmore_limit] => 100
    [show_icons] => 1
    [show_print_icon] => 1
    [show_email_icon] => 1
    [show_hits] => 1
    [show_noauth] => 0
    [show_publishing_options] => 1
    [show_article_options] => 1
    [save_history] => 1
    [history_limit] => 10
    [show_urls_images_frontend] => 0
    [show_urls_images_backend] => 1
    [targeta] => 0
    [targetb] => 0
    [targetc] => 0
    [float_intro] => left
    [float_fulltext] => left
    [category_layout] => _:blog
    [show_category_title] => 0
    [show_description] => 0
    [show_description_image] => 0
    [maxLevel] => 1
    [show_empty_categories] => 0
    [show_no_articles] => 1
    [show_subcat_desc] => 1
    [show_cat_num_articles] => 0
    [show_base_description] => 1
    [maxLevelcat] => -1
    [show_empty_categories_cat] => 0
    [show_subcat_desc_cat] => 1
    [show_cat_num_articles_cat] => 1
    [num_leading_articles] => 1
    [num_intro_articles] => 4
    [num_columns] => 2
    [num_links] => 4
    [multi_column_order] => 0
    [show_subcategory_content] => 0
    [show_pagination_limit] => 1
    [filter_field] => hide
    [show_headings] => 1
    [list_show_date] => 0
    [date_format] => 
    [list_show_hits] => 1
    [list_show_author] => 1
    [orderby_pri] => order
    [orderby_sec] => rdate
    [order_date] => published
    [show_pagination] => 2
    [show_pagination_results] => 1
    [show_feed_link] => 1
    [feed_summary] => 0
)
```

and

```
��j Object
(
)
```

With both can be serialized but not be unserialized by PHP. I decided to comment out the line cloning the data. After this the 'Getting Started' article didn't give the error any more, but showed the article as normal. The names of the objects raise concern with me, I've never seen such names before in PHP When I print other variables. I for instance get `Joomla\Register\Register Object`

But this did not fix the login problem.

I'm pretty completely at a loss.

Edit:

In the database a session is created:

```
session_id=d984e4c528453009a9ba77ace5f58d9e,
client_id=1,
guest=1,
time=1442060444, 
data=zq9ZfjiuKiKB8tyC3yEB2yREY_tylC7CD1K14M6XLIt01gwDUMTq1yY5DMVYhVUDTtPS1vmM1BFdBECdnMg0eKHlAWdZ9JwYdRNFKZl8wU_eAF61Im9d5dIy2r7Kt34upgLDzY4hmDA2EimXm-d2uKO9J6vElLCbcwFZGR2yHUq21RBQvx1wdnBMjk78z6UlI0zF9YXO6wH4WNdUlROJ85BDdhccRBrw52rzRxkpker23_nzeBK4K6nw_Eb2GN-fRAQ25PZr0XxRAtbrGAF5JvGHJDwbL9Kc34eDgOYcBwXlbCICA7be1S64K54VwYUdXZqlnqDbWUEUKb3EdvQZExY5IYRcP5McdiM2s-RYwmWpvtpIIu8VMNn1T_5c_K0gonIdngPUQeiI4r0NOncGWWt7qNjoamX8u86WVVqIVY9ufxb8Wo5INgLIUhy_TAhfBl_K5CrjNToR-13RVnBjZ1RPBeBj4hHubA2t7IZ6zbSOdPdPLbsQVYD2lsU-PjXvcN1eeqkTYNUi8U-qtfYyH-mkidMHK8hbtkS53CKGuo_D4r1K8nO16VlOI0xhK2qR2zSaykXtX_DaAkRF3AI0BvZHBrsxSc6QE2jZkRPYkdyyUnyDoyx2FTSNcPv-JrJ2uDochowEm8jyCazqIXywnmAuYb3bkMN38A7lA1IRhlrCGJY_3xpx6ZBtch4u9bUtBXuQY3E5oV5nPfL2__vW7ZADW5sUHP-e8obRo30b40iIZ3yi6DmnutdGekUi_6a9GyGVDkP3NwAoglbj5pHiLJVhfFZL54XFCuN1sHtlbismkomsx-AkOY6F27hDNCI4B4qFVX87-NF_hk2DWPqRWynCR6OCsLUPkD0apgnr-ea7KPt8qij_eu8Rn6J-RMrgHS7SE314kKoJscEXxwwnBsaoqRCwzwjEl5yHmZYS-bCocgqMGAeOf-VUmCdX-UnqGz5qgXwFBOq4tFrfJ6RQizXVdxkHml3dDmGUPMSHT9To4WXAowT8glRtMdsmZmBigM88xftj3Yr-iYTxiAwfzxPF_T8hG53d1rfPEAm0n8a_q7c6JKy9Z2HrklaqxbQzwGl6r3PwRMCaDxZ_vqq4fsPP4142I4SnAuF2WzEBFOkIyh4EUKesFV4sl4BOc19uIYhz5HSHJybh_9hlV8eB6OSHZYccvaM7F6b46Lh6g-1yDUKazCK8z-fTXHJzf6gn7UFLiWorXCQZspwK_LiW3Huv2B0HIJKxi0fEb8Zmq6juViV8LABZjG_8ZEgDvQ4InahV4k7dKIyQG3gPicaDFLqgtGnwfO2FkU3L1SUU1eAGGcyZDH15RPgfimFiwHt2A5AEPKsnh2jye3X5L53CNaB69ISY0ETVhYzXc7bGi0SADbsAVbFixXZ39IqbFyDaX3rSS0047n_riZm8xNsR6DJ2kB0R1_eWBfN_APqgynK5-Yucis4PuyblY_YwIPs2AQz5iBFgnGGCkbZDxiVG6K6CRBorqpvOPUcBN0fzyOL0xp5WfC5x3nGcbAeVOBBIh1nN7Pj1vDyjfAWGAuw5vP3g647iUmDKaxcRWZ-yGIw.,
userid = 0,
username = ''
```

Nothing else seems to change. The jos1_users table has an lastvisit date and time set the the date and time of installing Joomla.

No new sessions are created in the database when trying to login multiple times.

With error reporting set to development nothing is reported when visiting and trying to login the administrator back end.

When visiting the site and a few seconds later trying to login the front end this is logged:

```
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:19 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 6 of 2159 bytes in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 82
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:19 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 6 of 19 bytes in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 82
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:19 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 693
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:28 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 8 of 615 bytes in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 82
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:28 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 8 of 19 bytes in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 82
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:28 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 693
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:29 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 8 of 2159 bytes in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 82
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:29 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 8 of 19 bytes in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 82
[12-Sep-2015 07:42:29 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/.../public_html/.../libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php on line 693
```

I also tried installing Drupal on the server to a different subdomain. The only thing it's able to display is these error/warnings. Again about serialization.

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 53 of 33869 bytes in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/cache.inc on line 438
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/module.inc on line 213
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/module.inc on line 89
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 53 of 33869 bytes in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/cache.inc on line 438
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/module.inc on line 213
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/module.inc on line 89
Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in /home/nningsh1/public_html2/test.iradis.org/includes/menu.inc on line 636
```

Comment: when you say "has correct setting for live site" do you mean it is blank? Because normally that is the correct setting. Also does the database say you are logged in after you do the login? When you say you have set all errors to display do you mean you have edited the configuration.php to make error reporting be "development"?

Comment: I've tested both with life site set to blank and to the full URL Joomla is hosted on. I've set `display_errors = On`
 in `.users.ini` and `$error_reporting = 'maximum';` in `configuration.php`. Currently I'm testing with `$live_site = '';`, `$lifetime = '15';` and `$session_handler = 'database';` I've tested with 90 and none. None of this makes any dirreference in behaviour.

Comment: So it seems like you are having two separate problems. One is not logging in successfully and the other is that you are getting these errors on rendering the article.  Am I correct that you are only getting the errors rendering after you have attempted the login but the article is okay prior to that?  Would you mind doing a test install with one of the sample data sets? I think trying testing would be  best or else the learn joomla one.

Comment: It could be two problems or one. If for instance both the article params and the session can not be unserialized because of the same error.

And no, the Getting Started welcome page is never shown. Not before trying to login and not after.

Comment: Okay that's important information that you didn't include in the initial question.  So you installed sample data but the first time you went to the home page you never got an article showing and you couldn't login. And you got through the installation without having to create your own configuration file? What version of PHP do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service provider changed PHP to not use FCGI for our domain. This fixed the problem. Both the serialization problem has been fixed, as is the login problem.